# Read - Write P7M Files

Tags: c#, certificate

I've used `iTextSharp` together with `Net.Pkcs11.dll` in order to sign `PDF` Files.
All works fine.

Now, I would be able to sign and read contents of any file type by writing and reading `p7m` files.

I've no idea where to start from.

I'm able to sign data through my Smart card and certificate with `Net.Pkcs11` `API` wrapper.

Now, I would be able to write and read CAdES-compliant `p7m` files (not encrypted), but I don't know `p7m` strucutre.
All what I know I have signed data as `byte[]`:

```
MySmartcardSession.Sign(arrayByteOfMyFile);
```

Have you some examples or suggestions?

Comment: There is an example here: http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2010/03/encryption-and-decryption-with-x-509-certificates/

Comment: No. The example you have posted doesn't use P7M structure and also it isn't able to read certificate from smartcard. Finally, it use p7m to encrypt message with public key, instead I'm looking for P7M Cades compliant.

Comment: You never mentioned CAdES in your question. Talking about "be able to write and read p7m files" is not enough if you want people to help.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. However that link is not useful..

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you can do it with Bouncy Castle... http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: bouncycastle's API creates P7M where no other P7m readers are able to decode its file, so I think ther's something to wrong in that library..